# Store Rails Json response in ember

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ember.js, response

I am working on authentication of a user .

currently i am posting a session with username and password . which will be sent to rails `bcrypt` for authentication ,if authentication is true then this will return a `json` of user object .

how will i grab this user in ember so that i can store it in my service .

Login Function :

```js
login(user) {
    console.log("this is working ")

    //this.get('sessionaccount').login(user)

    this.store.createRecord('session', {
        email: this.currentModel.email,
        password: this.currentModel.password
    }).save().then(function(data) {
        console.log(data.id) 
        this.id = data.id
        this.get('sessionaccount').login(data)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ember Data is meant to be used together with resources. It doesn't work well with other types of data. I assume you will only have one session client-side, so I would not recommend to model that one with Ember Data but using plain fetch instead:

```js
async login() {
  let response;

  try {
    response = await fetch('/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Content-Type: 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: this.currentModel.email,
        password: this.currentModel.password
      })
   });
  } catch (error) {
    // handle connectivity issues
  }

  if (!response.ok) {
    // handle server-side errors
    // this may include wrong credentials
  }

  // parse the returned data as json
  let data = await resonse.json();

  // do something with the returned data
}
```

I'm using `async` / `await` instead of a chaning `.then()` cause it's much easier to read in my opinion.

If the data returned by the server is a resource representing data that should be handled with Ember Data, you could (and should) load it into the store, using [`pushPayload()` method of Ember Data's `StoreService`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/3.15/classes/Store/methods/pushPayload?anchor=pushPayload).